# Set range equal to multiple named ranges with line break

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I am setting a range variable equal to a list of ranges. The list is so long that I would like to use a line break for easier management. However, I am having a tough time getting the syntax. I've tried many combinations.

The code in one line works and looks like this (with a lot more named ranges):

```
Dim xNamedRangeList As Range
Set xNamedRangeList = Range("NamedRange1, NamedRange2")
```

My best attempt so far is this.

```
Set xNamedRangeList = " Range(""" & _
"NamedRange1," & _
"NamedRange2" &_
""")"
```

Debug.print looks like this: Ranged("NamedRange1, NamedRange2")

While this works in debug.print, it sure doesn't work when I set xNamedRangeList equal to it. I think I've turned the formula into a string, but not sure how to make it work in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be as shown by @TimWilliams.
But you say *"with a lot more named ranges"*, so please note that the length an address used in `Range(address)` can have is limited to 255 characters. So if you have a lot of ranges you might hit that limit and it doesn't work.

If that might be the case you must use the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union):

```
Dim xNamedRangeList As Range
Set xNamedRangeList = Application.Union(Range("NamedRange1"), Range("NamedRange2"))
```

Line breaks are always <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by underscore <kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
Set xNamedRangeList = Application.Union(Range("NamedRange1"), _
Range("NamedRange2"))
```

Comment: What would the syntax for line breaks be?

Comment: @KelvinNg Syntax for line breaks is always Space followed by underscore and enter. That will continue it in the next line.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like sometimes & is required and sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @KelvinNg no. the `&` is only to concatenate strings and actually has nothing to do with the linebreak. It only occurs because if you want to linebreak a string, you have to split it into multiple strings that you then need to concatenate with `&`. But that can also be done in one line `"String1" & "String2" & "String3"` is the same as `"String1String2String3"` but the first one can be line breaked while the second one cannot. • Since in my example we line break different range objects and not strings we don't need a `&`.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. This means the Range() functions accepts a string as it requires a & for line breaks. While Application.Union accepts a different type of variable.

Comment: @KelvinNg didn't get your last question. But everything that begins with a `"` and also ends with a `"` is a string. so in `Range("Name")` the `"Name"` is a string. The `Union` needs different `Range` objects as parameters (see the linked documentation, it says the arguments need to be range objects).

Answer (score 2):

```
Set xNamedRangeList = Range("NamedRange1," & _
                            "NamedRange2," & _
                            "NamedRange3")
```

Answer (score 0):

If NamedRange1  and  NamedRange2 are variables then try:

```
Range(NamedRange1 + NamedRange2)
```

Comment: Don't use the plus sign `+` to concatenate strings. Therefore the `&` sign must be used. If you use `+` you might get really odd side effects. Excel always tries to calculate then.